# Elasticsearch Service (AWS) on Rails - Timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

[UPDATE] I just add the current endpoint for this case (for a few days)

I'm using ElasticSearch with Rails, I'm using this gems:
- elasticsearch-rails
- elasticsearch-model

When I run elasticsearch in my development (My computer) my setting is ok. But when I use the endpoint for Elasticsearch AWS appear this message in my rails app:

> "Faraday::TimeoutError: Connection timed out - connect for
>   search-production-shipit-45cu5wkligv2ythnfozcnthsoi.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com port 9200"

I added this file in my initializer: elasticsearch.rb

```
Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new host: "search-production-shipit-45cu5wkligv2ythnfozcnthsoi.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com"
```

When I enter in my endpoint show elasticsearch information ok.

This is my policy in Amazon Elasticsearch (Anyone can connect for this example)

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-east-1:090358380644:domain/production-shipit/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

On the other hand, when I execute this command:

```
curl -XGET 'search-production-shipit-45cu5wkligv2ythnfozcnthsoi.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com'
```

The endpoint return this:

```
{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Meld",
  "cluster_name" : "090358380644:production-shipit",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.5.2",
    "build_hash" : "62ff9868b4c8a0c45860bebb259e21980778ab1c",
    "build_timestamp" : "2015-04-27T09:21:06Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.10.4"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Comment: Is `url_name` only there for example or is that in your actual code?

Comment: Timeout on connection usually indicates that the url is not correct, or there is no connectivity between your machine and the endpoint.

Comment: @toddmetheny is only an example.

Comment: @Slicedpan is weird because I can connect for terminal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Amazon hosted elasticsearch changes the default port from 9200 to the default http/https ports (80 and 443) - note how your curl command doesn't specify a port

On the other hand the elasticsearch ruby libraries assume the elasticsearch default of 9200. You can specify the port by specify a URL (with the `url` option) or with

```
Elasticsearch::Client.new hosts: [
  { host: 'some-host',
    port: '443',
    scheme: 'https'
  } ]
```